# uniformly continuous hemeomorphism

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an open set,$\varphi:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a homeomorphism.If $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous,how to prove $\Omega =\mathbb{R}^m$?

I try to prove $\partial \Omega =\emptyset$, and assume $x\in \partial \Omega$ try to conclude some condradictions. How to get it?